# GPS myservice doesn't update in time intervals

Tags: android, service, gps

I am trying to run a service where the user selects a time interval and in this time the GPS location is updating.

My app doesn't update location.

The selection class where I get the google maps working (this was working before):

```
public class selection extends FragmentActivity implements OnMyLocationChangeListener{

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    double latitude=0.0;  
    double longitude=0.0;
    String code_value="";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selection);



        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if....
            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment  = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

       ....

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.rb_normal){
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
               ....
                else if(checkedId == R.id.save_location){

                     new Thread(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                            //retrieve this value from configure class
                             code_value=getIntent().getStringExtra("code_value");
                                              postData(Double.toString(latitude),Double.toString(longitude),code_value);
                         }

                     }).start();
                }
      ...


    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        ...


    }

    public void postData(String lat, String lo ,String code) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet  htget = new HttpGet("www.test.com"+lat+"/"+lo+"/"+code);

        try {
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htget);
            String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, resp, 5000).show();
                       ...

}
```

The myservice class where I use alarmmanager in order to update the location.

```
public class myservice extends IntentService {

    private Context mContext;
    private Handler mHandler;
    public myservice(String name) {
        super(name);
    }


    // call from startService()
    public myservice() {
        super("MyService");
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            String time_value;
            time_value=(String) intent.getStringExtra("time_value");
            final long thetime=Long.parseLong(time_value);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Start service using AlarmManager
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
                Intent intent = new Intent(myservice.this,selection.class);
                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(myservice.this, 0, intent,
                        0);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        thetime*1000, pintent);
             // Tell the user about what we did.
                Toast.makeText(myservice.this, "Configured time interval",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The configure class where I start the service:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn:
             edit11=edit1.getText().toString();
             edit22=edit2.getText().toString();
             Intent i=new Intent(this,selection.class);
             i.putExtra("code_value",edit11);
             Intent k=new Intent(this,myservice.class);
             k.putExtra("time_value",edit22);
             this.startService(k);
             Intent l=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(l);  
             break;

     }
```

Comment: This is just a guess: Is the lat value intended to be part of the test.com url or is there missing a `/` between? Look code `HttpGet  htget = new HttpGet("www.test.com"+lat+"/"+lo+"/"+code);` Now there is not a slash appended between them.

Comment: @mico:I put it there just as an example.It doesn't matter.thanks